# How do I transform linux date from 14-01-2015 to 14-1-2015?

Tags: linux, shell, date

How do I transform linux date from 14-01-2015 to 14-1-2015

I don't want that 0 in the %m

Here is the command I'm using:

```
DATE=$(date --date yesterday +%d-%m-%Y)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Strongly recommend you output dates with `%Y-%m-%d` -- that format (ISO standard) sorts the same chronologically and lexically.

Answer (score 5):

try:  `date --date yesterday +%d-%-m-%Y`

read the man page:

```
   By default, date pads numeric fields with zeroes.  The following optional flags may follow ‘%’:

   -      (hyphen) do not pad the field

   _      (underscore) pad with spaces

   0      (zero) pad with zeros

   ^      use upper case if possible

   #      use opposite case if possible
```

Comment: np:) Please accept the answer if you find it useful. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want a leading zero for the month, you probably don't want a leading zero for the day either: `+%-d-%-m-%Y`. But I second glenn jackman's suggestion to use the ISO 8610 standard format `+%Y-%m-%d` unless you have a specific reason not to.